# Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "No URL signature provided" in Symfony Application

Tags: php, symfony, mapbender3

I am working on a Symfony application ([Mapbender3](http://Mapbender3.org)) and new to this framework (as I am a Codeigniter guy). The application is supposed to load the view page using ajax request but it does not. I checked the console and it said:

```
Failed to load resource: http://localhost/mapbender3/web/app.php/owsproxy/?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmapbender3%2Fweb%2Fapp.php%2Fapplication%2Fmopwmaps%2Finstance%2F9%2Ftunnel&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&LAYERS=cite%3ARoad_Master&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=62.69026197435,31.478060912429,70.30973802565,35.521939087571&WIDTH=2400&HEIGHT=1273
the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

And a error:

```
GET http://localhost/mapbender3/web/app.php/owsproxy/?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhos…60912429%2C67.942541429504%2C35.521939087571%26WIDTH%3D908%26HEIGHT%3D1273 500 (Internal Server Error)
jquery.js:9659
```

I followed the error in the jquery.js file and it was:

```
xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );
```

Moreover, The logs/prod.log stated:

```
[2015-11-22 07:54:42] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "No URL signature provided" at C:\wamp\www\mapbender3\owsproxy\src\OwsProxy3\CoreBundle\Controller\OwsProxyController.php line 95 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 500): No URL signature provided at C:\\wamp\\www\\mapbender3\\owsproxy\\src\\OwsProxy3\\CoreBundle\\Controller\\OwsProxyController.php:95)"} []
[2015-11-22 07:54:42] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
```

Please let me know what I have to do to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a Symfony error. As you are using Google Maps APIs, the request needs to include authentication params as defined here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json
  ?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA
  &client=gme-YOUR_CLIENT_ID
  &signature=YOUR_URL_SIGNATURE
```

Comment: I am not using Google Maps. The call is supposed to load some map from the same symfony application itself. Map are retrieved from a local GeoServer.

Comment: @AfghanDeveloper OK, sorry about that. But I don't think so that the error is coming from the Symfony Core Framework, you should test the call to the local GeoServer with a simple raw PHP at first.

Comment: Well the connection is there, when I load the page, the list of the maps gets loaded. but clicking on them causes the error status 500: Internal Server Error